# Make link_settings global in gyp project

Tags: linux, makefile, gyp

I have multiple gyp files, most of which create a static library and the main gyp files which combines all of them to create an exectuable. I wanted the libraries to link dynamically and I am using the following in my main gyp file:

```
  'link_settings': {
    'libraries': ['-lgcc', '-lc', '-lm'],
```

But when I start compiling on my linux box running Ubuntu, for all the static libraries compilation, the makefile LIBS:=  is empty except the main gyp file which creates the executable. Is there a way i could make these link_settings global so they get included in the Makefile of every target?

UPDATE : Will adding  libraries to  all_dependent_settings in the main target make it work?